# Edit a microk8s secret using kubectl in airflow

Tags: containers, airflow, kubectl, kubernetes-secrets, microk8s

I am trying to edit a secret that we have stored in airflow server using microk8s kubectl.

At the moment all I can do is find the coded secret using:

```
microk8s kubectl get secrets/MySecret -o jsonpath='{data}'
```

I want to edit the secret called 'host' within MySecret. Any advice on how to do this using the command line? I have tried edit secret command but I can't seem to interact and amend the code. I know I have done this before using the command line but can't remember how unfortunately.

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Comment: Try using < kubectl edit secrets/MySecret -o jsonpath='{data}' > this will open the editor and it allows you to update the encoded Secret values in the data field.

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
kubectl get secret mysecret -o json | jq '.data["secrect_to_change"] = "base64-encoded_password"' | kubectl apply -f
```